# How to pass a parameter to a Post action method which contain "&" inside our ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, encoding, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following Post action method which accept username & password:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserInfo(string username, string password)
{
```

and I am testing it using FireFox RESTCleint add-in, where I am passing the URL + the Header as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` + the username/password, as follows:

[image]

Things are working well, but in case the username or the password contain this character `&`, then the logic will break, as it seems ASP.NET will assume that what comes after `&` is a new parameter and not part of the parameter value. How can I fix this issue?

And is it an issue with my code or with the FireFox plugin or with encoding the parameters?

Second question, if I want to specify the technical specification for calling this Acton method from external applications, then what is the data encoding needed for the parameters?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use **URL encoding** on your strings that you pass to a REST call - that's a general requirement - has nothing to do with Firefox, any plugins, or your code - you just need to think about this before calling a REST method. See e.g. this site here: https://developers.google.com/maps/url-encoding or any other web development reference site

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the useful reply. so if i pass the paramters after url encoding them, then do i need to change my action method code ? or they are capable of decoding the parameter values out of the box? and what i need to pass inside the http request header then?

Comment: Hmm.. good question - not entirely sure if the ASP.NET runtime will automagically URL decode any parameters it gets. I'm tempted to say it does - but haven't done that myself in a long time, so I can't really say for sure. But that's tested quite easily - just call your method with URL encoding in place, and see if you get "proper" text back - or if you need to apply URL decoding to those param values yourself

Comment: @marc_s ok thanks will test this .. but what shoul be passed inside the http request header ? espically for the content-type?

Comment: @marc_s now i test it , where i url encode the parameters values, and the action method has decode them out of the box.. but if i url encode the while query string (username=test.test&password=$$$$$) not just the parameters values the username/password will be null inside the action method

Comment: You do *not* want to encode the whole query string, but each "value" part separately. Think about it: if the whole query string is encoded, how would the receiver see which encoded "&" is really the separator?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing yes correct, this is how it works.. but since i will be url encoding the paramters values is passing "the Header as application/x-www-form-urlencoded" the correct way of doing things? as if i remove this header my action method will be called but the parameters will be null